# cmake errors on osx Mojave

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to install open-source software named "Neper". The installation instruction can be found [here](https://github.com/NotRealEngineering/Neper-Gmsh-installation-guide). Everything seems to be OK but when I install Neper with `cmake ..` the errors shown as follows:

```
CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES)
```

I'm using macOS 10.14.6

Comment: What compiler and version are you using? Old versions of AppleClang didn't support OpenMP.

Comment: Please tell me the command to check the compiler. gcc --version?

Comment: (base) 192:Downloads km$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin